# Ubuntu 14.04 server tomcat7 won't start on reboot

Tags: 14.04, server, tomcat7

I have tomcat7 running on server for helpdesk ticketing system (SysAid). After a reboot the tomcat7 service does not start up.

In my catalina.out file when I grep for tomcat7 I get the following:
`WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/sysaid.war
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/sysaid.war
Initializing log4j with: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/sysaid/./WEB-INF/log4j.properties
Initializing log4j with: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/sysaid/./WEB-INF/log4j.properties
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT`

The help desk program log files show no mention of tomcat7 errors.

When I run a startup script for the program I get the following:
`Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out’: No such file or directory
./catalina.sh: 385: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent`

I also checked to make sure it was already set to run at startup through rc.d with the command: `sudo update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults`

Here's what I get: `System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/tomcat7 already exist.`

I've removed it and re-added it, with no change. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check this to see if it is related:

[Tomcat7 installation failed via apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556954/solvedtomcat7-installation-failed-via-apt-get-on-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1)

Basically, there is a dependency that may be missing (fixed with `sudo apt-get install libtomcat7-java`), but assuming you already did this, it seems the apt-get package is generically FUBAR and requires post-install massaging (which typically I don't recommend as `apt-get reconfigure` or other package commands may result in undesirable consequences).

Thus, installing the .tgz (from Apache) manually may be the most stable path of least resistance.

Comment: Here's my results: `libtomcat7-java is already the newest version.
libtomcat7-java set to manually installed.` So it looks like it's already updated. I guess I'll try the .tgz install manually.

Comment: A complete reinstall of the program did not work. I additionally flushed out the logs and let the program recreate them, this did not help.

Comment: Not entirely surprising.  Did you look in any logs and more importantly, are the log errors different this time?  For instance, instead of missing files/directories, this time it might be apparmor or some other issue that might not have occurred using a proper debian package.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your system variables.

You've `CATALINA_HOME` defined, but there is no `CATALINA_BASE`, therefore by default it's the same as `CATALINA_HOME`, but it's not correct.

> `CATALINA_BASE`: (Optional) Base directory for resolving dynamic portions of a Catalina installation.  If not present, resolves to the same directory that CATALINA_HOME points to.

Normally you should see something like:

```
# /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /tmp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /var/run/tomcat7.pid
```

If these variables are not present, either you may define them manually:

```
. /etc/default/tomcat7
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7 CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7 CATALINA_PID=/var/run/tomcat7.pid CATALINA_TMPDIR=/tmp
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run
```

or configure your `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` startup script correctly, as normally it should have these variables at the end:

```
# Directory where the Tomcat 6 binary distribution resides
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/$NAME

# Directory for per-instance configuration files and webapps
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/$NAME
```

Check content of `catalina.sh` for more details, as it describes all Environment Variable Prerequisites.

Otherwise re-install your Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the issue of directory problems. It was after I had removed tomcat 7 and tried reinstalling it. When I had first removed it though, I didn't touch the libtomcat7-java package. Once I ran into the fact it might be that package causing the problem, I did a full removal and reinstall and Tomcat came right up:

Remove (making sure to include the libtomcat7-java package this time):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge tomcat7 tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples libtomcat7-java
```

Reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples libtomcat7-java
```

The first thing you'll notice is that tomcat will start on it's own without an issue. Then you can continue to configure it properly.